# How do I prevent Linq DataContext.ExecuteQuery from modifying data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, t-sql

I have a custom scripting engine that allows the user to execute queries on a TSQL data set.  The query is free form and maps directly to a call to 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteQuery'

I want the user to be able to query data, and return results, but NOT modify the data as this would be a security issue.

Currently I check the string for the following keywords: insert, update, alter, create, delete, drop, truncate, merge and exec.

However, I suspect there is a better way, like setting the context to read only or some other method that doesn't rely on my remembering or parsing all possible sql statements, etc..

Comment: Always operate in a transaction and always rollback after executing.

Comment: Now that's outside of the box thinking. :) Certainly sounds like it would work.

Comment: The inherent issue here is that the DataContext is superseded and ExecuteQuery is directly executed against the database.  Any handy-dandy DataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled flag would be ignored, since DataContext.SubmitChanges() does not need to be called for the query to be executed.  As such, you're limited to rolling back transactions, adding new users, or manually examining your Sql Statements for naughty keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about connecting to the database using a user that only has the data reader permission? This would eliminate the problem completely and enables out-of-the-box decent error reporting. Checking a SQL string for words seems sketchy at best, for example a user can do `SELECT ... INTO` which is not handled by the keywords you mentioned up until now.

Comment: I agree the keyword method is 'sketchy'.  Using another user would certainly handle it.  However you just gave me a new problem.  Now I will need to modify the installer to make sure the user is properly created. :)